# How do I get the image path from a imagebutton when the button is clicked Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Better question would be is it possible to get the image path from the image button when clicked? I'm using the gridview in asp.net and I'm trying to get the image path from the image button when it's clicked so I can populate my next page with more detailed information by using the image path to set the next page or is there a better way of going about this? Any help is greatly appreciated. 
I've provided the code for my gridview and I need help with the code behind( which I do not have at the moment)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CourseId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    CssClass="table table-striped table-responsive" Style="background-color: white; border: 5px solid green; padding-right: 10px;">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CourseImage" SortExpression="CourseImage">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseImage") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("CourseImage") %>' PostBackUrl="~/DetailPage.aspx" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseId" HeaderText="CourseId" SortExpression="CourseId" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName" HeaderText="CourseName" SortExpression="CourseName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ShortDescription" HeaderText="ShortDescription" SortExpression="ShortDescription" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Department], [CourseImage], [CourseId], [CourseName], [ShortDescription] FROM [Table] WHERE ([Department] = @Department)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Department" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: which button you are speaking?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the image url, you can do this. But in order to work you need to remove the `PostBackUrl="~/DetailPage.aspx"` from the LinkButtons. If not you cannot access it's properties on the page it has posted to.

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender as an imagebutton
    ImageButton imageButton = sender as ImageButton;

    //get the imageurl propery
    string imageUrl = imageButton.ImageUrl;

    //redirect to the details page as querystring
    Response.Redirect("/DetailPage.aspx?image=" + Server.UrlEncode(imageUrl), false);

    //or set the image url as a session and then redirect to the details page
    Session["imageURL"] = imageUrl;
    Response.Redirect("/DetailPage.aspx", false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this really help.